# How to check whether a string is well-formed XML in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a database with tables that have schemaless XML columns which contain arbitrary non-XML data (plain-text). Here a sample script to gerenate and fill such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1), 
  XmlColumn XML NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('<root><child /></root>');
INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('Foo, this is not XML');
INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('<root><parent><child /></parent></root>');
GO
```

How can I (preferred) enforce that only well-formed XML can be added?
Or else, how can I determine which entries are not well-formed and `NULL` them out?

I have read several posts that suggest a `CAST` / `CONVERT` in conjunction with a `TRY CATCH`, (e.g. [stackoverflow.com/questions/14753119](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753119/)), but I never get an exception, the `CAST` / `CONVERT` always succeeds:

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML;
DECLARE @isValid AS BIT = 1;
BEGIN TRY
  SET @xml = CONVERT(xml, 'Foo')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  SET @isValid = 0;
END CATCH;
SELECT @isValid; -- returns 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use try_convert().  This will return null if the conversion fails.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use tempdb
go

drop table if exists TestTable;
drop table if exists TestTablewithcheck;
drop function if exists dbo.mywellformedxml
go

CREATE TABLE TestTable (
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1), 
  XmlColumn XML NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('<root><child /></root>');
INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('Foo, this is not XML');
INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('<root><parent><child /></parent></root>');
INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('<root><child /></root>Foo, this is not XML');
INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('<root xmlns="test"><child /></root>');
INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('<!-- comment -->');
INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('<!-- comment --><root><child /></root>');
INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('<noroot><child /></noroot><noroot><child /></noroot>');
INSERT INTO TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES ('<?pi my processing instruction?>');
GO

create or alter function dbo.mywellformedxml(@xml xml)
returns bit
with schemabinding
as
begin
    return
    ( 
        isnull(
        (
        select 1
        where @xml.exist('/*[1]') = 1 --root..
        and @xml.exist('/*[2]') = 0 --..only..
        and @xml.exist('text()') = 0 --..without text..
        ), 0)
    )
end
go

CREATE TABLE TestTablewithcheck (
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1), 
  XmlColumn XML NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTablewithcheck] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC) ON [PRIMARY],
  constraint chkwfxml check(dbo.mywellformedxml(XmlColumn) = 1)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

declare @i int = 1
while @i <= 9
begin
    insert into TestTablewithcheck(XmlColumn)
    select XmlColumn
    from TestTable
    where id = @i;
    
    select @i = @i + 1;
end
go

select *
from TestTablewithcheck;
go


select *, dbo.mywellformedxml(XmlColumn) as wfxml
from TestTable
go

drop table if exists TestTable;
drop table if exists TestTablewithcheck;
drop function if exists dbo.mywellformedxml
go
```

Comment: lptr, nice solution. Please up-vote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following three approaches.

**Method #: 1**

We will find out if there is at least one root level node.
By the way SQL Server allows not well-formed XML, i.e. just XML fragments without a root element. That's why I added that use case to the sample data population.

Also, I added an XML comment for completeness.

The outcome's meaning:

- 2 (or any number greater than 1) - an XML fragment
- 1 - well-formed XML
- 0 - no XML elements, text or comment nodes.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, XmlColumn XML NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @TestTable (XmlColumn) VALUES 
(N'<root><child /></root>'),
(N'<city>Miami</city><city>Orlando</city>'),
(N'Foo, this is not XML'),
(N'<root><child /></root>Foo'),
(N'<!-- -->'),
(N'<root><parent><child /></parent></root>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * 
    , XmlColumn.value('count(/*)', 'INT') AS Result
FROM @TestTable;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
| ID |                XmlColumn                | Result    |
+----+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | <root><child /></root>                  |         1 |
|  2 | <city>Miami</city><city>Orlando</city>  |         2 |
|  3 | Foo, this is not XML                    |         0 |
|  4 | <!-- -->                                |         0 |
|  5 | <root><parent><child /></parent></root> |         1 |
+----+-----------------------------------------+-----------+
```

**Method #: 2**

By using an `instance of element()` XQuery construct

```
SELECT * 
    , XmlColumn.query('<root>{
        for $x in /*
        return
        if ($x instance of element()) then <r/> else ()
        }</root>').value('count(/root/r)', 'INT') AS Result
    , XmlColumn.query('for $x in .
        return if ($x eq /*[1]) then "well-formed" else "not well- formed"').value('.','VARCHAR(20)') AS [well-formed]
FROM @TestTable;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+
| ID |                XmlColumn                | Result |   well-formed   |
+----+-----------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+
|  1 | <root><child /></root>                  |      1 | well-formed     |
|  2 | <city>Miami</city><city>Orlando</city>  |      2 | not well-formed |
|  3 | Foo, this is not XML                    |      0 | not well-formed |
|  4 | <root><child /></root>Foo               |      1 | not well-formed |
|  5 | <!-- -->                                |      0 | not well-formed |
|  6 | <root><parent><child /></parent></root> |      1 | well-formed     |
+----+-----------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+
```

**Method #: 3**

A complete solution. The algorithm is based on comparison of counts: count of any type of nodes vs. count of elements only. Additionally, it gives a breakdown of node types in the NodeList column for easy understanding of what is going on.

```
;WITH rs AS
(
SELECT * 
    , XmlColumn.value('count(/node())', 'INT') AS NodeCount -- any type of nodes
    , XmlColumn.value('count(/*)', 'INT') AS ElementCount -- elements only
    , XmlColumn.query('
    for $x in /node()
    return if ($x instance of element()) then text {"element()"}
    else if ($x instance of text()) then text {"text()"}
    else if ($x instance of comment()) then text {"comment()"}
    else if ($x instance of processing-instruction()) then text {"processing-instruction()"}
    else ()
    ') AS NodeList
FROM @TestTable
)
SELECT *
    , CASE
        WHEN NodeCount = 1 AND ElementCount = 1 THEN 'well-formed'
        WHEN NodeCount = 2 AND ElementCount = 1 
           AND LEFT(NodeList, 24) = 'processing-instruction()' THEN 'well-formed'
        WHEN NodeCount > 1 AND (ElementCount = NodeCount) THEN 'XML fragment'
        WHEN NodeCount > ElementCount THEN 'not well-formed'
        ELSE '???'
       END AS Result 
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| ID |                XmlColumn                | NodeCount | ElementCount |      NodeList      |     Result      |
+----+-----------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|  1 | <root><child /></root>                  |         1 |            1 | element()          | well-formed     |
|  2 | <city>Miami</city><city>Orlando</city>  |         2 |            2 | element()element() | XML fragment    |
|  3 | Foo, this is not XML                    |         1 |            0 | text()             | not well-formed |
|  4 | <root><child /></root>Foo               |         2 |            1 | element()text()    | not well-formed |
|  5 | <!-- -->                                |         1 |            0 | comment()          | not well-formed |
|  6 | <root><parent><child /></parent></root> |         1 |            1 | element()          | well-formed     |
+----+-----------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Your version does not work with a string like `<root><child /></root>Foo, this is not XML`, it returns 1 although it is not valid XML. @lptr's version returns correctly 0.

Comment: But I like your way of distinguishing between XML documents and XML fragments.

Comment: @Christoph, Your table definition has that column as  `XmlColumn XML NOT NULL`. So it will not accept `<root><child /></root>Foo,` in the first place.

Comment: @Christoph, please connect with me on LinkedIn

Comment: It does accept `<root><child /></root>Foo`, same as `Foo, this is not XML`. The XML column behaves like an NVARCHAR(MAX) without checking anything - for that reason I asked this question in the first place. But as I said, I like your code and together with lptr's version I can detect all 3 variants (no XML, XML fragments, XML document) properly.

Comment: @Christoph, I updated Method #2. Check it out.

Comment: @Christoph, I added Method #3, the best out of three approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, SQL Server *can* convert a value like `'foo'` to XML, so just trying the conversion won't actually work. What you could do, however, is check to ensure that the value starts and ends with `'<'` and `'>'` (which valid XML should have) and perform a `TRY_CONVERT`:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(xml,XMLColumn) IS NOT NULL AND XMLColumn LIKE '<%>' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsValid
FROM (VALUES ('<root><child /></root>'),
             ('Foo, this is not XML'),
             ('<root><parent><child /></parent></root>'))V(XMLColumn);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1b6934b91c58993515cb48c5e473f3c)

Comment: Valid XML can include arbitrary white space at the start and the end, so this is not completely accurate. The `TRIM` functions are of limited help since XML allows more than just spaces.